# C++ Is there something like RVO for passing temporary objects to functions?

Tags: c++

With RVO it is possible to create an object from a returned object without move or copy. Is it possible to do something similar when passing an object to a function?

```
class SomeClass {
    int a;

public:
    SomeClass(int _a)                   {a = _a;        std::cout << "created\n";}
    SomeClass(const SomeClass& source)  {a = source.a;  std::cout << "copied\n";}
    SomeClass(SomeClass&& source)       {a = source.a;  std::cout << "moved\n";}
};

void create(SomeClass&& source) {
    SomeClass some_object( std::move( source));
    //p_some_object = new SomeClass( std::move( source));
    //new( p_some_object) SomeClass( std::move( source));
}

// ...

create(SomeClass(15));
```

In this example the result is "created, moved". (GCC 5.4 / C++11 / -O3) It is the same with new or placement-new. There is no branch or anything so why can't it be created without move?

Comment: How else would you populate a local property of `SomeClass` without moving it? What if you set `a` to be a reference instead?

Comment: This seems to be redundant, just leave `void create(SomeClass some_object)`. So result will be `"created"`

Comment: @tadman: I assume the OP is hoping that the construction of `SomeClass(15)` would somehow be inlined in a way that the compiler recognized as not actually requiring the creation of the temporary (so `SomeClass some_object` is the only one constructed). Pretty sure if that's necessary, `create` should just accept `SomeClass some_object` directly, which gives the compiler enough information to (potentially) optimize out the first `SomeClass`.

Comment: A move shouldn't cost much (if anything). Have you checked what the compiler actually does (look at the generated asm)? Modern optimizing compilers are pretty smart. Also; is this an *actual* performance problem in your code? If not, why do you care?

Comment: @VTT Tried it. For me it is still moved. If I remove the std::move then it is copied.

Comment: @AdyAdy I mean completely removing your function local variable `SomeClass some_object( std::move( source));` leaving just an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the compiler must inline and analyze enough to recognize that the temporary object referred to by `source` is unnecessary. Beyond that, even RVO is intended for value semantics; when `&&` references come into play, it's not guaranteed.

As it happens, GCC would handle your case just fine if you followed the general rule for C++ function parameters: ["If you need to copy the argument anyway, accept the argument by value."](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113221447/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Accepting by value means that, in cases like this where the argument is constructed as part of the call, no copy or move is needed (it can, and on GCC, is, "RVO"-ed).

```
class SomeClass {
    int a;

public:
    SomeClass(int _a)                   {a = _a;        std::cout << "created\n";}
    SomeClass(const SomeClass& source)  {a = source.a;  std::cout << "copied\n";}
    SomeClass(SomeClass&& source)       {a = source.a;  std::cout << "moved\n";}
};

void create(SomeClass some_object) {

}

int main() {
    create(SomeClass(15));
}
```

which if you [try it](https://tio.run/##dZBNi8IwEIbv8ysGBWmQCrLupa178Qd42KsgcRolS5MpJvUi/eubTf2q1HVO887HM8NLdZ0eiEIYa0tVUyosNDt/VNJ8AVAlncNvNmp1yc6AMbT1KHOAutlVmrJL7TGTdN2tFPgaZ4nL2Mrv2vkyy4gbj0WBI4o3vSo3dpS3AySxdb7XE3TcHEmJG/KqZh14gORa/0/sWU@w/sm3RMOnO7CNDpxYl3h9vEfGbaO2vPtR5EW0DFoA6FwxUttE3EwcbiXzTyEisg3hl/aVPLiQxttLmk7ni5CuP/4A), shows only the `created` message.

If the goal is for `create` to construct the object for you, then use a templated function with argument forwarding so you construct it within `create`, e.g.

```
template<typename T, class... Args>
T create(Args&&... args) {
    T some_object(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    return some_object;
}

int main() {
    auto foo = create<SomeClass>(15);
}
```

which solves the problem by passing the constructor arguments as forwarding references, and constructing the object itself inside `create`, avoiding any additional construction, [as seen here](https://tio.run/##dZDNSsNAEMfv@xRDhZBQGyjqpUkD4gN4MEehbCfbsJL9YHejlpJXN@5uW1Oszmk@f/@ZQa0XLeI43nCJXd8wKLmyzjAqKjLlesc77vYVIdhRa@FFCfYUvQMBb1w6oAUhut92HFcxxz6197mbmtPQtqEZXNuBwtqXinNsXbNaoeodlCXM0O/jWPMqZ8UQ2RMSlbQXEglY1Rtk2Ql5jPIA/oVUmv9NnFgXsGnJf4lCvZ@Bg3@FY0J3fuvS7TWTVDCobyF@L89zeDStrUgNx8vSECZJKFDvZaev1l5MsI3avjF0aVTbKfNBTVPG@TQ2@6nM64UBw1xv5OVUQQZCSPi7oFymZ/JRtvw5tUqXDwEyjOMX7jra2nHh9dY4ny/vx8Xz3Tc).

Comment: Thanks! The point of the create function is to actually create "some_object" from the parameter. The caller provides the object, and "create" knows where and how to create it. With "new" for example. I was wondering if it's possible to do this without moving the object.

Comment: @AdyAdy: So is `create` a templated general purpose function? Something else? It's a little strange to need the special function, especially when you don't seem to have a return type pinned down. If you wanted to construct the object within the function, maybe you want something like `std::make_shared` where you accept the constructor arguments and construct the object inside `create`?

Comment: @AdyAdy: I added an example of the common pattern for constructing within a helper.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, in my real-life code I have a templated container class and its "create" function is like "addElement" / "pushBack". Sometimes I copy an existing element but sometimes I want to construct one from the arguments when I call "create".Your example seems to work but with that I have to specify the arguments for the element constructor and there might be more than one constructors.

Comment: @AdyAdy: Yeah, for cases like that, you usually use two different methods. `std::vector` is a model here; it has one method for inserting existing objects (`push_back`), and another for constructing a new element directly into the container (`emplace_back`). This avoids the ambiguity of having the same method with a prototype for copying in a class being mistaken for one that is creating a new class via a single argument constructor.

Answer (score 0):

RVO don't happen with reference nor it happen when creating another object from a function parameter.

If you change your reference parameter to a value parameter, RVO will be applied to it, but not the local object:

```
void create(SomeClass source) { 
    SomeClass otherObject = std::move(source); // No RVO, object constructed from parameter
}

// ...    

create(SomeClass{15}); // RVO applied to source parameter
```

However, you can achieve it using lambda as function parameters:

```
template<typename C>
void create(C source) {
    SomeClass some_object{source()};
}

// ...

create([]{ return SomeClass{15}; });
```

You can check the [live output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05d24fca6688c70b)